# many to many in redbeanphp is not full

Tags: redbean

I've created bean called user

```
$user =  = R::dispense('user');
$user->sharedInstrument = $instruments;
```

And create an instrument where the owner is a user and many users can view it

```
$instrument = R::dispense('instrument');
$instrument->sharedUser = $users;
$instrument->owner = $owner;
```

The problem is when I load an instrument `$instrument->sharedUser` seems to only consist of the owner. Is there a way to get around this other than using `R::related($instrument,'user')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to do it use preload with an alias.

```
R::preload($instrument,array('sharedUser'=>'user'));
```